# C# Is it possible to model bind multiple options?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding, multiple-instances

I have a dropdown on which you can select multiple options. 
[image]

The code for this dropdown is:
[image]

How can i bind multiple 'devices' in C# so that when this dropdown is loaded
model binding will automatically select all options which are passed into the view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html.DropdownListFor selected value not being set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476530/html-dropdownlistfor-selected-value-not-being-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case you should use another helper - `@Html.ListBoxFor` it should generate `select` element with `multiple` attribute.

```
//note that i use MaintanceDevices property
@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.MaintanceDevices, new SelectList(Model.Devises, "ID", "Description"), new { @class = "multiselect form-control"})
```

Also, don't set `id` attribute in helper. It's better to create another property in your ViewModel:

```
public List<int> MaintanceDevices { get; set; }
```

Populate it in Controller and MVC automatically generate right markup for your `select` element bind in on form POST.

Answer (score 1):

Devices property in your model should be a list of Ids (where is a simple type like int or a string) and not a list of Device models (Since you are using `new SelectList(Model.Devices, "ID", "Description")` in the Helper it is i see that Model.Devices is a collection of complex object)

So your model should look like:

```
public List<Device> AvailableDevices { get;set; }

public List<string> Devices { get;set; }
```

and the Helper should be

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m=>m.Devices,new SelectList(Model.AvailableDevices , "ID", "Description"))
```

or

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Devices,new SelectList(Model.AvailableDevices , "ID", "Description", new {multiple="multiple"})
```

post action should receive either a `List<string>` as an argument or a full model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(List<string> devices)
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Submit(YourModel model) 
//where YourModel model is the same type that you are using to render your view
```

Answer (score 1):

In this situations, i would do the following inside the viewmodel

```
public string Devices { get; set; }
List<int> innerList;
public List<int> List
{
    get
    {
        if (this.innerList == null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Devices))
            {
                this.innerList = this.Devices.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                this.innerList = new List<int>();
            }
        }

        return this.innerList;
    }
}
```

Where `Devices` is the binded property with the dropdown, which it returns all items separated by `,`.
When you try to access `List` it will separate the items and return it as a `List<int>`.

And i'm parsing it to `int` because normally i see `int`'s as ID's

But i'm looking forward for a better option.

**PS**

I do this when working with `Select2`