# DropDownListFor select value based on value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Good Day everyone. 
I have next question.

I have Edit form with few DropDownList controls on it.
I need to bind selected value in DropDownListFor based upon data which I have in my db.

What I have is next:

Model:

Supplier

```
public class Supplier{
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }       
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}
```

Delviery

```
public class Delivery{
    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryCode { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }        
}
```

ViewModel for Delivery Edit Screen:

```
public class DeliveryEditViewModel{
    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }        
    public string SelectedCompanyName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
<dd>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCompanyName, new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
</dd>
```

Controller:

```
 // GET: Deliveries/Edit
public ActionResult Edit(int? id){   
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        DeliveryEditViewModel model = db.Deliveries.Include(s => s.Supplier).Include(a => a.Auction).Include(q => q.Quality).Include(t => t.BulbType)
                .Where(d => d.DeliveryID == id)
                .Select(x => new DeliveryEditViewModel{
                    DeliveryID = x.DeliveryID,
                    SelectedCompanyName = x.Supplier.CompanyName
                })
                .Single();               
    model.Suppliers = db.Suppliers.Where(s => s.IsActive == true).Select(x => new SelectListItem{
        Value = x.SupplierID.ToString(),
        Text = x.CompanyName
    });
    return View(model);
}
```

Problem is that I can't setup selected value in DropDownListFor based upon data which I already have inside my database.Instead I have DropDown control with first element active always.
I already tried solutoin from [Html.DropdownListFor selected value not being set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476530/html-dropdownlistfor-selected-value-not-being-set) but still I have first value selected instead of real one.

Hours of researching and already bold hair makes me to stop and ask for a help. 
Please help me to figure out how it could be possible.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `Suppliers` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` Why in the world are you creating another identical one using `new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Value", "Text")` in the view? You need to set the value of `SelectedCompanyName` to match one of the options (i.e one of the values of `SupplierID` in your `Suppliers` table (but your code suggest the property should be `int` not `string`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you so much. I do not know how can I miss this. Now it works perfectly. You save me )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Suppliers` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` Why in the world are you creating another identical one using `new SelectList(Model.Suppliers, "Value", "Text")` in the view? You need to set the value of `SelectedCompanyName` to match one of the options (i.e one of the values of `SupplierID` in your Suppliers table (but your code suggest the property should be `int` not `string`) by @StephenMuecke

Answer (score -1):

As what i will advice you not create SelectListItems at controller level. What you can do is :

```
public class DeliveryEditViewModel
{
    public int DeliveryID { get; set; }        
    public string SelectedCompanyName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Supplier> suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
 // GET: Deliveries/Edit
public ActionResult Edit(int? id){   
    db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        DeliveryEditViewModel model = db.Deliveries.Include(s => s.Supplier).Include(a => a.Auction).Include(q => q.Quality).Include(t => t.BulbType)
                .Where(d => d.DeliveryID == id)
                .Select(x => new DeliveryEditViewModel{
                    DeliveryID = x.DeliveryID,
                    SelectedCompanyName = x.Supplier.CompanyName
                })
                .Single();               
    Model.suppliers = db.Suppliers.Where(s => s.IsActive == true);
    return View(model);
}
```

View :

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCompanyName, ((IEnumerable<Supplier>)Model.supplierss).Select(x => new SelectListItem()
           {
               Text = x.CompanyName.ToString(),
               Value = x.SupplierID.ToString(),
               Selected = (Model != null) && (x.CompanyName == Model.SelectedCompanyName)
           }), "-- Select Supplier --")
```

This is a very usefull trick, you can change Text or Value or Selected Value or Default Selected options without changing at controller and building it again to reflect.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using ViewBags. To be honest for now I can't see any benefit from using ViewBag. Maybe I miss something. But anyway thank you for the advice.

Comment: @ЖенькаСидоров I have, edited my post. Please have quick view