# Set selected option in dropdownlist razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code that generates a drop-down list with values:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.BeslutsinformationstypId, VardemangderHelper.BeslutsInformationsTyperForInteckningarGetList(), new { @class = "form-control")})
```

Now I want to a select option per default. I have tried the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.BeslutsinformationstypId, VardemangderHelper.BeslutsInformationsTyperForInteckningarGetList(), new { @class = "form-control", Selected = VardemangderHelper.BeslutsInformationsTyperForInteckningarGetList().First(x => x.Value == "320").Selected = true})
```

But that don't work. How can I set selected option based on the values from `VardemangderHelper.BeslutsiinformationsTyperForInteckningarGetList()`?

Is It possible to do this in Razor?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20008816/713789

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to select an option by default when the view is rendered then you need to set the `Model.BeslutsinformationstypId` property before returning the view like below:

```
var model = // My model instantiation
// He set some properties if you want
model.BeslutsinformationstypId = 320;

return View(model);
```

If you can set it in your action, you can do it inside the view but I prefer to set it into controller action:

```
@{
     Model.BeslutsinformationstypId = 320
}
```

And your dropdown will still be the same line of code you wrote in your question :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.BeslutsinformationstypId, VardemangderHelper.BeslutsInformationsTyperForInteckningarGetList(), new { @class = "form-control")})
```

Comment: This is the first, concise, and utterly correct answer I've run across this. I wish Microsoft would fix their junk and make the constructor work correctly!