# Send Dropdown Selected Value from View to Controller using "DropDownListFor" in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

### **Unable to send selected Value from view to controller.I am using DropdownlistFor to send data with From Tag.**

@using (var form = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Form("ReportList", "Report").Type(FormType.Vertical).FormMethod(FormMethod.Post).HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "reportForm", @data_bv_message = "This value is not valid", @data_bv_feedbackicons_valid = "fa fa-check", @data_bv_feedbackicons_invalid = "fa fa-times", @data_bv_feedbackicons_validating = "fa fa-refresh", area = "Admin" })))
                    {

```
                        <div class="col-md-2">@Html.Label("Status:", new { @class = "" })  </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.Status, new List<SelectListItem>
                                                                  { new SelectListItem(){ Text="NEW", Value = "NEW" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="PAID", Value = "PAID" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="PENDING", Value = "PENDING" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="FAULT", Value = "FAULT" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="PROCESS", Value = "PROCESS" }
                                                                  }, "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control " })</div>

                        <div class="col-md-2"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button> </div>

                        </div>

                        }
```

---

```
 public ActionResult ReportList()
        {
            List<ReportModel> reportList = new List<ReportModel>();

            string FilterStatusList = reportmodel.SelectedStatus;

            List<InsuranceDetails> insuranceList = _insuranceDetailsService.GetAllInsurances().ToList();

            //Stroed Procedure calling
            // List<InsuranceDetails> filterdata = _insuranceDetailsService.GetDatatableFilterbyStatus().Where(a => a.InsuranceStatus.Equals("DropdownValue")).ToList();
            try
            {
                foreach (InsuranceDetails currentitem in insuranceList)
                {
                    ReportModel currentItemmodel = new ReportModel();

                    currentItemmodel.InsuranceId = currentitem.InsuranceId;
                    currentItemmodel.EncodedInsuranceId = Encode(currentitem.InsuranceId.ToString());
                    currentItemmodel.PlateNumber = currentitem.PlateNumber;
                    currentItemmodel.ReceiptNumber = currentitem.ReceiptNumber;
                    currentItemmodel.VehicleType = currentitem.VehicleType;
                    currentItemmodel.CustomerName = currentitem.CustomerName;
                    currentItemmodel.InsurancePreiod = string.Concat(currentitem.PeriodStartDate, "-", currentitem.PeriodEndDate);
                    currentItemmodel.UserName = currentitem.UserName;
                    currentItemmodel.BranchName = currentitem.BranchName;
                    currentItemmodel.TotalPremiumPrice = currentitem.TotalPremiumPrice;
                    currentItemmodel.InvoiceNumber = currentitem.InvoiceNumber;
                    currentItemmodel.InsuranceStatus = currentitem.InsuranceStatus;
                    currentItemmodel.UploadedImagePath = string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentitem.InvoiceImage) ? "" : ImageBaseUrl + "ImageUploads/" + "OriginalSize/" + currentitem.InvoiceImage;      
                    reportList.Add(currentItemmodel);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                string message = AppLogger.CreateMessage(e);
                AppLogger.LogFileWrite(message);
            }
            TempData["ReportList"] = reportList;
            return View(reportList);
        }
```

Comment: DropdownList must have id and name property as in your Model.

So, add 'SelectedStatus' as id and name property to your dropdown.

Comment: My Model has :- public string SelectedStatus { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> FilterStatusList { get; set; }  ,as I add SelectedStatus  in view ,Got error that ,content does not exist

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476530/html-dropdownlistfor-selected-value-not-being-set

Answer (score 1):

DropdownList must have id property as in your Model. So change 'Status' to 'SelectedStatus' as below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedStatus, new List<SelectListItem>
                                                                  { new SelectListItem(){ Text="NEW", Value = "NEW" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="PAID", Value = "PAID" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="PENDING", Value = "PENDING" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="FAULT", Value = "FAULT" },
                                                                    new SelectListItem(){ Text="PROCESS", Value = "PROCESS" }
                                                                  }, "Select Status", new { @class = "form-control " })
```

Comment: Again I am getting the same issuse that :- List<ReportMode> Does not contain the definition of SelectedStatus

Comment: Where you get the error, either in controller or in view? and I need clarification about whether you submit List<ReportModel> or just an instance of ReportModel ?

Comment: Please check whether the reportModel object has null value or not, in the action public ActionResult ReportList(ReportModel reportmodel)

Comment: I got error in View page .I submit   List<ReportModel> not a Report Model

Comment: But your action in controller is not for List<ReportModel>

Comment: Sorry I just edit my controller,you can see now.This is my actual controller action

Comment: What is the workflow of this module? As I came to know that, you need an insurance list for report, based on status, right?

Comment: May be it will be helpful to post the content of your View.

Comment: Yes.... I need an insurance list for report, based on status.please suggest me what is my controller and  view code

Comment: In your action, please add a line as var availFormVariables = Request.Form; and send what values you are getting in availFormVariables.